# JavaScript prototype, issue in calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js

My prototype definition is below

```
 var DupPlayer = function(strName){
   this.name = strName;
 }  

 var FreqTab = function(strMsg,strName){
   this.value =strMsg;
   this.original = strName;
   this.dupPlayers = new Array();

   FreqTab.prototype.addDup = function(dup){
     this.dupPlayers.push(dup);
   }
 }
```

I'm creating array object with string as key.

```
 var freqTab = new Array();
 if(freqTab[key]==undefined){
   freqTab[key] = new FreqTab(strMsg,strName);
 }else{             
   var temp = freqTab[key];
   temp.addDup(new DupPlayer(strName));             
 }
```

Getting error "TypeError: temp.addDup is not a function".

Please help me where i got wrong in the function call.

*[edit]*
Found that this issue occures when the key is '**reduce**'. :(

console.log(freqTab[key]) gives below output, only when key is reduce, object is stored as function.

```
{ value: 'sleeping', original: 'Pug', dupPlayers: [] } 
{ value: 'black', original: 'Sur', dupPlayers: [] } 
[Function: reduce]
```

Comment: If `freqTab[key]` is undefined, you are defining it as new object. But if not then its just a simple element of array and not your object. Hence `addDup` is not available.

Comment: What's the value of `key`? Along with `strMsg` and `strName`. Mind creating a snippet or fiddle so we can see the error message?

Comment: Well, why are you using an array when you want to use string-valued keys? Change to `freqTab = {};`.

Comment: var freqTab = new Array();
 if(freqTab[key]==undefined){
   freqTab[key] = new FreqTab(strMsg,strName);
 }else{             
   var temp = freqTab[key];
   temp.addDup(new DupPlayer(strName));             
 }

Comment: where you calling the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error:

> temp.addDup is not a function

Is actually an interesting functionality that happens when you attempt to access a undefined/invalid item inside an array. When you attempt to access:

```
freqTab["reduce"]
```

It will actually read it as the actual native `reduce()` function. The same thing happens with other functions such as `freqTab["sort"]`. Then it states that `addDup` is not a method of `reduce`.

Note in your code the array is empty, and since you are accessing a item by a string you probably rather want to use an object:

```
var freqTab = { 'reduce': ... };
```

Specifically you might be looking for:

```
var freqTab = { 'reduce': new FreqTab(strMsg,strName) };
```

Comment: @spencer, curious question, when i try `function test(){}; var arr = []; console.log(arr["test"]);` This return `undefined`, instead of function. So is it just restricted to functions that are part of `Object` or any other parent scope?

Comment: @Rajesh It seems that this only happens to native JavaScript functions. So even if you have made a `test()` function it would still be `undefined` for `arr["test"]`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use prototype outside the definition like this

```
 var FreqTab = function(strMsg,strName){
   this.value =strMsg;
   this.original = strName;
   this.dupPlayers = new Array();
 }

 FreqTab.prototype.addDup = function(dup){
   this.dupPlayers.push(dup);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, he should put the prototype method outside the constructor, but how does that explain the error message he is getting? `FreqTab.prototype.addDup` should still be getting assigned when the constructor is called.

Comment: I dont think that you can create a prototype inside the constructor.. if so, the `addDup` function is never created

Comment: Well, you shouldn't of course, but you can, so his problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: *"I dont think that you can create a prototype inside the constructor"* Why not? Why should it not be possible to assign to `FreqTab.prototype`?

Comment: Hello all, I'm getting this issue only when the value of the key is 'reduce'

Answer (score 0):

As I have explained in my comment, issue is in this condition

> **Comment:** If `freqTab[key]` is undefined, you are defining it as new object. But if not then its just a simple element of array and not your object. Hence `addDup` is not available.

```
var freqTab = new Array();
if (freqTab[key] == undefined) {
  freqTab[key] = new FreqTab(strMsg, strName);
} else {
  var temp = freqTab[key];
  temp.addDup(new DupPlayer(strName));
}
```

Instead try this:

```
var freqTab = new Array();
if (freqTab[key] == undefined) {
  freqTab[key] = new FreqTab(strMsg, strName);
} 

if(freqTab[key] instanceof FreqTab){
  var temp = freqTab[key];
  temp.addDup(new DupPlayer(strName));
}
else{
  console.log("Not an object")
}
```

Comment: This will avoid the error, but why the object is changed to function when the key is 'reduce'. I just printed the freqTab[key] and got these

{ value: 'sleeping', original: 'Pug', dupPlayers: [] }
{ value: 'black', original: 'Sur', dupPlayers: [] }
[Function: reduce]